# Using UPDATE does not load image to my database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, image

I have a form that loads an image to a local 'uploads' folder so I know that part works.  However, the form is also supposed to load the image to a user table - avatar field, but there is no image when I check the user table.

I use a users.php for the adding of and updating of images.

```
<?php
include('..config/connection.php');

$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1
$id = $_GET['id'];

$storeFolder = '../uploads';   //2

$name = 'image'.'_'.date('Y-m-d-H-i-s').'_'.uniqid().'.jpg';

$q = "UPDATE users SET avatar = '$name' WHERE id = $id";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3             

    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  //4

   // $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];  //5

    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $name;  //5

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6

}
```

The user.php should also display the updated image - associated with the user.

```
<?php if (isset($opened['id'])) { ?>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
            Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
            var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#avatar-dropzone");
        });

    </script>
<?php } ?>

<h1>User Management</h1>

<div class="row">...

divs and other stuff
 ....   

        <!-- form section-->    
        <form action="index.php?page=users&id=<?php echo $opened['id']; ?>" method="post" role="form">

            <?php if($opened['avatar'] != '') { ?>

                <img src="../uploads/<?php echo $opened['avatar']; ?>"

            <?php } ?>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="first">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first" value="<?php echo $opened['first']; ?>" name="first" placeholder="First Name" autocomplete="off">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="last">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last" value="<?php echo $opened['last']; ?>" name="last" placeholder="Last Name" autocomplete="off">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" value="<?php echo $opened['email']; ?>" name="email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="status">Status</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="status" name="status">
            <option value="0" <?php if (isset($_GET['id'])) { selected('0', $opened['status'], 'selected'); } ?>>Inactive</option>
            <option value="1" <?php if (isset($_GET['id'])) { selected('1', $opened['status'], 'selected'); } ?>>Active</option>
            </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" value="" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="passwordv">Verify Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordv" value="" name="passwordv" placeholder=" Type Password Again" autocomplete="off">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>

            <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
            <?php if (isset($opened['id'])) { ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $opened['id']; ?>">
            <?php } ?>
        </form>

        <?php if (isset($opened['id'])) { ?>

            <!--dropzone form -->
            <form action="uploads.php?id=<?php echo $opened['id']; ?>" class="dropzone" id="avatar-dropzone">
              <div class="fallback">
                <input name="file" type="file" />
              </div>
            </form>

        <?php } ?>

    </div><!-- col-md-09 end -->

</div><!-- row end -->
```

I'm missing something, but what?

Comment: Right now you are just firing your query without caring in the slightest whether it succeeds or not. Please go _read up_ on how to do some basic error handling.

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: Enable error reporting: add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors. You should also check whether the values you're passing in (e.g. the ID in the $_GET) is actually what you expected. You need to do some error handling, and some debugging. Simply saying "it doesn't work" indicates you haven't even begun to investigate properly...